# SQL: query get all users for a specific group and each user with all groups

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have 3 tables: `USERS`, `GROUPS`, `GROUP_USERS`

I need to get a list of users that are in a specific group and all users needs to contain all groups that are members of.

I tried something like this:

```
select group_concat(g.name) as groups
     , u.* 
  from USERS u 
  JOIN GROUP_USERS gu 
    ON gu.USER_ID = u.ID 
  JOIN GROUPS g 
    ON g.ID = ug.GROUP_ID 
 WHERE ug.GROUP_ID = SOMEID 
 GROUP 
    BY u.ID
```

But this will return all users in group with id SOMEID and will concat only that one group that was use for search, even if a users is member of multiple groups.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  This does not make sense:  "all users needs to contain all groups that are members of".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see.  You want all groups for a subset of users that are in one group.  That would be:

```
SELECT u.*, group_concat(g.name) as groups
FROM USERS u JOIN
     GROUP_USERS gu
     ON gu.USER_ID = u.ID JOIN
     GROUPS g
     ON g.ID = gu.GROUP_ID
GROUP BY u.ID
HAVING SUM(g.id = ?) > 0;
```

In other words, you need to move the filtering to the `HAVING` clause.